# Faceing difficulty with virtumart 2.0.20 installation on joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I had download virtumart extension 2.0.20b form its official site.com_virtumart.2.0.20b_extract_first, a 3.88 MB Zip archive. now the problem is when I am trying to install the virtumart from extension manager it is generate below error. so please help me to get my self out from this situation.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the file size is greater than 2MB.

You should set the directive `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` to let's say `"5MB"`.

Comment: after done changes as you say i am getting "The installer cannot continue until file uploads are enabled for the server". this error

Comment: Try setting `file_uploads` to `1`

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't decompress the `com_virtumart.2.0.20b_extract_first.zip` and try directly install this file , So i want to tell it's clearly mentioned in the manual, first you need to decompress the `com_virtumart.2.0.20b_extract_first.zip` then you have two zip file in it, then you have to upload both the zip file through the extension manager.

Also if you directly upload this to a server then you need to check your folder permission in the site like

1. administrator->component,
2. administrator->languages,
3. components,
4. languages
5. plugins,
6. modules
7. tmp  and log

Set these folder permission to `(777)` for a moment until you extension installed successfully.

Also check you server settings for `upload_max_filesize`,`post_max_size`,`max_execution_time`. Hope this will help you.

**Update:**
If you cannot change you `php.ini` setting for `file_upload` then you can try it with `.htaccess` file , Just add the below line in to your `.htaccess` file.

```
php_flag file_uploads 1
```

**For fixing the safe path warning see this link:**

[How to fix Safe Path is empty error in VirtueMart?](http://www.gavick.com/magazine/how-to-fix-safe-path-is-empty-error-in-virtuemart.html)

Comment: @AnandMehta I thinks it's because your server settings. Try to contatc your hosting provider and set the file upload on in the server.

Comment: after putting comment here i had also try with minimum size file... tar... now thing is i am getting new error when i am trying to install it from extension manager. This error is "The installer cannot continue until the file uploads are unable for the server" now how can i fix it?

Comment: installation is done but with warning of safe path is not set

Comment: @AnandMehta Ok good to know you have done your installation. And the warning about the safe path, Please see my updated answer, provide a link to solve it or you can check in manual for set the safe path. hope it will help.